# List of all possible Google weather API "Conditions"

Tags: google-api, weather-api

Anyone know of all the possible weather conditions Google's API will put out?

I've got to match up my icons to the forecast, and I can't find a list of conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was mentioned: http://www.blindmotion.com/?p=73 though it may not be complete, as it isn't something released by Google. It probably covers about 99% of cases though, barring random enhancements and releases to the weather api by Google staff.

EDIT:

blindmotion.com appears down, internet archive has the content of the page: http://web.archive.org/web/20111001141159/http://www.blindmotion.com/2009/03/google-weather-api-images/ . (Note, from 2009)

https://gist.github.com/bzerangue/806934 (by Vijay, listed in below answers) is likely a more up to date list

Comment: @QadirHussain I've added a link to the old page content, but I suspect you'll be better off with Vijays' or Beno's listings.

Answer (score 10):

I found this list which looks more complete than any other that I've seen

<strike>http://dennisdel.com/content/conditions.xml</strike> (**NOT AVAILABLE ANYMORE (Jan 2016)**)

```
<conditions>
 <type>PARTLY SUNNY</type>
 <type>SCATTERED THUNDERSTORMS</type>
 <type>SHOWERS</type>
 <type>SCATTERED SHOWERS</type>
 <type>RAIN AND SNOW</type>
 <type>OVERCAST</type>
 <type>LIGHT SNOW</type>
 <type>FREEZING DRIZZLE</type>
 <type>CHANCE OF RAIN</type>
 <type>SUNNY</type>
 <type>CLEAR</type>
 <type>MOSTLY SUNNY</type>
 <type>PARTLY CLOUDY</type>
 <type>MOSTLY CLOUDY</type>
 <type>CHANCE OF STORM</type>
 <type>RAIN</type>
 <type>CHANCE OF SNOW</type>
 <type>CLOUDY</type>
 <type>MIST</type>
 <type>STORM</type>
 <type>THUNDERSTORM</type>
 <type>CHANCE OF TSTORM</type>
 <type>SLEET</type>
 <type>SNOW</type>
 <type>ICY</type>
 <type>DUST</type>
 <type>FOG</type>
 <type>SMOKE</type>
 <type>HAZE</type>
 <type>FLURRIES</type>
 <type>LIGHT RAIN</type>
 <type>SNOW SHOWERS</type>
 <type>ICE/SNOW</type>
 <type>WINDY</type>
 <type>SCATTERED SNOW SHOWERS</type>
</conditions>
```

**EDIT**
There is a new one here based on the original list:
https://gist.github.com/806934

It removes these from the list

```
<type>ICE/SNOW</type>
<type>WINDY</type>
<type>SCATTERED SNOW SHOWERS</type>
```

and adds:

```
<type>HAIL</type>
```

Probably wouldn't hurt to use all of them anyway

Answer (score 6):

That link was broken for me.  Here's a list I found on another forum:

```
"Clear 
Cloudy 
Fog
Haze 
Light Rain
Mostly Cloudy 
Overcast 
Partly Cloudy
Rain 
Rain Showers 
Showers
Thunderstorm 
Chance of Showers 
Chance of Snow 
Chance of Storm 
Mostly Sunny
Partly Sunny 
Scattered Showers 
Sunny"
```

Comment: Be warned. There's a Chance of Snow, but never Snow. Maybe this list was compiled in the middle of summer in only one region.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the best list I could find: http://www.blindmotion.com/?p=73

You may want to consider alternate APIs that are formally supported and documented. Yahoo!'s [Weather RSS feed](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) is a handy, easy-to-use API. I use the [National Weather Service's API](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/xml/) for one of my projects because I need to pull the forecast for a specific time frame in the future and it lets me do that in a reasonably straightforward way.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I gave Coder the check mark as he most closely answered the question, but I am definately looking into another api... mostly because google doesn't go beyond a 4 day forecast and my spiffy little weather carousel doesn't look very cool with just four panels.

Comment: I just noticed you gave the link too.. but coder was first.. gah, I hate having to decide on answers sometimes

Answer (score 1):

I compiled this one, it has everything, and so far I don't think I missed anything.

```
Clear
Sunny
Partly Sunny
Mostly Sunny
Scattered Thunderstorms
Showers
Scattered Showers
Rain and Snow
Overcast
Light Snow
Freezing Drizzle
Chance of Rain
Partly Cloudy
Mostly Cloudy
Chance of Storm
Rain
Chance of Snow
Cloudy
Mist
Storm
Thunderstorm
Chance of TStorm
Sleet
Snow
Icy
Dust
Fog
Smoke
Haze
Flurries
Light Rain
Snow Showers
Hail
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/806934

Answer (score 0):

Some more: Mist, Dust, Icy, Smoke, Sleet